# Does CRM online allows to create ActiveXObject() inside HTML web resource?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dynamics-crm-2011

I want export a HTML table into an Excel sheet using IE8 or Outlook.
Because i am working in Dynamics CRM Web-Resource, is nothing but a html page.

When i create ActiveXObject as :

```
var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
```

It says that

"**Automation server can't create object**".

I have changed the setting In IE for ActiveX by going into the Tool-> Internet Option-> Security-> Custom Level.

I have tried this in a web-resource(html page) and

also in .js file(fired onclicking of ribbon button) but still getting same error..:(

Please help me.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look at the right side of this page. You'll find `Related` link list with plenty of similar questions...

Comment: Yes, i found this before posting this question but i did not get the answer, i have tried that mentioned over there..that is why i am posting new question and though i am accessing from CRM that is why i created a new thread..

Comment: Did you read scunliffe's last comment? In that comment there are all reasons, why ActiveX is not working.

Comment: I guess you are talking about this.

**1.) the object type doesn't exist (e.g. a typo in the name) or 
2.) you don't have permissions for this user, on this site, in this zone**

then how to solve this.
I need to export a html table into an excel sheet.

Comment: Make sure you've selected a correct zone in Security options (epascarello's answer), though I'm not familiar with CRM... Also there are several security items to check, one or two is not enough.

Comment: Hi Teemu,
I found that creating new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application") is ok if MS-Excel is installed in your system otherwise it will give error that '**Automation server can't create object.**'

I have tried this in other system(MS-Excel installed) and it executed with a just warning.

Comment: LOL, so it's reason number one:  `1.) the object type doesn't exist...`.

Comment: :)..
but instead of this it is throwing something else..